flutter better_player custom controls problem
i'm implementing custom controls for flutter better_player widget, it worked fine but the problem is that the custom controls are stuck on screen (always visible), unlike the default material or cupertino controls which visibility can be toggled.
  BetterPlayerController? _betterPlayerController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _betterPlayerController = BetterPlayerController(
      BetterPlayerConfiguration(
        controlsConfiguration: BetterPlayerControlsConfiguration(
          playerTheme: BetterPlayerTheme.custom,
          customControlsBuilder: (controller, onControlsVisibilityChanged) =>
              // I believe onControlsVisibilityChanged is responsible for visibility toggle
              CustomControlsWidget(
                  controller: controller,
                  onControlsVisibilityChanged: onControlsVisibilityChanged),
        ),
      ),
      //dataSource etc...
    );

    super.initState();
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final provider = Provider.of<SeriesVideoProvider>(context);
    final seriesVideo = provider.seriesVideo;
    final mediaQuery = MediaQuery.sizeOf(context);
    print(mediaQuery.width);

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: seriesVideo == null
          ? kProgressIndicator
          : _betterPlayerController != null
              ? Center(
                  child: Stack(
                    alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
                    children: [
                      AspectRatio(
                        aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                        child:
                            BetterPlayer(controller: _betterPlayerController!),
                      ),

                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                        child: Container(
                          width: mediaQuery.width / 12,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: mediaQuery.width / 15),
                          child: Stack(children: [
                            ClipRRect(
                              child: BackdropFilter(
                                filter:
                                    ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 10, sigmaY: 10),
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                      horizontal: mediaQuery.width / 90,
                                      vertical: mediaQuery.height / 90),
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Seriez',
                                    style: GoogleFonts.cairo(
                                      fontSize: 15,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ]),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              : kProgressIndicator,
    );
  }

and this is my custom controls widget:
class CustomControlsWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final BetterPlayerController? controller;
  final Function(bool visbility)? onControlsVisibilityChanged;

  const CustomControlsWidget(
      {super.key, this.controller, this.onControlsVisibilityChanged});

  @override
  State<CustomControlsWidget> createState() => _CustomControlsWidgetState();
}

class _CustomControlsWidgetState extends State<CustomControlsWidget> {


  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      widget.onControlsVisibilityChanged;
    
    return Container(
      height: 50,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.purple.withOpacity(0.2),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
      ),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
          InkWell(
            onTap: () async {
              Duration? videoDuration =
                  await widget.controller!.videoPlayerController!.position;
              setState(() {
                if (widget.controller!.isPlaying()!) {
                  Duration rewindDuration =
                      Duration(seconds: (videoDuration!.inSeconds - 2));
                  if (rewindDuration <
                      widget
                          .controller!.videoPlayerController!.value.duration!) {
                    widget.controller!.seekTo(Duration(seconds: 0));
                  } else {
                    widget.controller!.seekTo(rewindDuration);
                  }
                }
              });
            },
            child: Icon(
              Icons.fast_rewind,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
          InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                if (widget.controller!.isPlaying()!)
                  widget.controller!.pause();
                else
                  widget.controller!.play();
              });
            },
            child: Icon(
              widget.controller!.isPlaying()! ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
          InkWell(
            onTap: () async {
              Duration? videoDuration =
                  await widget.controller!.videoPlayerController!.position;
              setState(() {
                if (widget.controller!.isPlaying()!) {
                  Duration forwardDuration =
                      Duration(seconds: (videoDuration!.inSeconds + 2));
                  if (forwardDuration >
                      widget
                          .controller!.videoPlayerController!.value.duration!) {
                    widget.controller!.seekTo(Duration(seconds: 0));
                    widget.controller!.pause();
                  } else {
                    widget.controller!.seekTo(forwardDuration);
                  }
                }
              });
            },
            child: Icon(
              Icons.fast_forward,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

is I mentioned the controls are working fine but they're always visible, I googled but never find implementation of onControlsVisibilityChanged

The main thing here is that your controls should decide it's own visibility and show/hide themselves on their own.
onControlsVisibilityChanged – this is callback you should call when your controls change their visibility, it has nothing to do with control's visibility itself, you just notify BetterPlayerController here that controls are hidden or shown.
You can see implementation of material controls here and try to re-implement it in your own controls. Key point (at least as I see them):

You can extend BetterPlayerControlsState instead of just State and get some useful overrides.
Wrap root Container in GestureDetector to track user's interaction with screen to decide whether controls should be shown or hidden. Default BetterPlayerMultipleGestureDetector can be used in there also.
Also use AnimatedOpacity to animate disappearing of controls as it done here in material

But overall conclusion – controls should manage it's own visibility.
